# Give link to download file from server

Tags: asp.net, file, url-rewriting, download, html

I use ASP.NET.

I have several audio files on the server and I should give user a temporary link for downloading. It meens that after several hours link should be unavailable
For example I give user: *www.mysite.com/files/111.mp3*, but how to protect *www.mysite.com/files/* from direct access and downloading by any user?Is the UrlRewriting what I need?

How can I make a temporary web-page/link for downloading and protecting files from direct access from adress line?

Maybe I should store files in database(I have SQL Server 2008)?Can it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need a way to manage the temp links (say a DB with time stamps) and when you get a request by one of these links, you gonna use `HttpHandlers` to intercept this request, fetch your database by the requested link.

if the given period of time still current, you will get the actual file from the server and let the `Httphandler` send it back to the user as a stream.

this way, the end user will still get the requested file, but he will see that he is getting the file from your temp link
(say: *http://mysite.com/files/kdhsdg52354d*) and will not be able to reuse it again after the your defined period.

sorry, I'm in a rush so couldn't format the answer better :).